# ASP.NET - how to change requested page names transparently?

Tags: asp.net

Very new to this subject and under the gun to come up with a solution. The problem is how I could load one of several versions of the same ASPX page, for any given page. E.g. unknown to the unsuspecting user who requests catalog.aspx, I would actually serve one of catalog_1.aspx, catalog_2.aspx, or catalog_3.aspx, etc.

Strange request indeed. It's due to an inherited decade-old product having inlined styles all over the ASPXs. Instead of re-writing the hundreds of ASPXs to be flexible, I'm trying to regexp-replace them to get versions suitable for various screen sizes. I'd then choose the best one after measuring window size at user login (and perhaps store the size in a cookie).

I thought this would involve some lower level object like an http handler. Close?

LJ

Update: I ended up doing this through url rewriting which works much better. The easiest place to do this in asp.net is apparently global.asax, and under Application_BeginRequest event. Call context.RewritePath(newpath, False) to send the request to a different page than requested.

In the way I did it, the destination page can change from request to request, and that apparently upsets postbacks, if the recipient of the postback isn't the exact version of the page that generated the viewstate. I tried to turn off viewstate validation but didn't help. So had to prevent flipping between versions once a user's logged in. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Server.Transfer` is probably the quickest way of doing just that.

```
string TransferTo = string.Empty;

if( Something ) 
     TransferTo = "catalog_1.aspx";
else if( SomethingElse )
     TransferTo = "catalog_2.aspx";
else
     TransferTo = "catalog_3.aspx";

Server.Transfer( TransferTo, false );
```

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.transfer.aspx)

**Note**
If the subsequent pages have postback controls on them, they will reveal the true URL of the page at that point. If that matters, then this method will not work.

Comment: I think you'll run into problems if there are postback controls on these pages. The action on the form will be `catalog_1.aspx`, so after post, I believe the URL bar will show `catalog_1.aspx`, not `catalog.aspx`, unless you do some more funkiness in the response.

Comment: You are correct, it will behave like that. They didn't specify, so I was just looking for the quickest option. Didn't know that it would matter after loading the page or not.

Comment: @JoeEnos sorry about that, wasn't paying attention when I saw the name. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I did come across this on the web before posting the question, and thought I needed something at a lower level, such that I didn't have to modify every aspx page. But looking at your answers I realized maybe I could put this code inside an ASCX that's used by every aspx. I think it should do the trick.

Comment: ...And I'm not too worried about page names changing in post backs. A regex match in the suggested code can pick out the file names clean. (All the versions will be functionally identical except file name and HTML size markups to match window sizes.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't like this method, but maybe you could use a full-window IFRAME to hold the appropriate page - `catalog.aspx` would be nothing but a big frame, and you could set the source of that frame in your codebehind.

Comment: Thanks, Joe. I briefly thought of this, but the problem was all links inside the pages will still point to the un-suffixed page names. I thought this needed to be a server-side trick.